# Convert numeric password to alphanumeric password according to input of a page

Tags: php

My code is receiving a 6-digit PIN via GET.

`test.php?password=123456`

I need to turn those numbers into letters according to a page.

The page generates an input with random values. Every two numbers represents a letter.

Ex:

`<input type="hidden" id="tecladoRandom" value="1,5,9,8,6,7,4,3,2,0" />`

In this case: `1,5` has the VALUE of A. `9,8` has the VALUE of B and so on, up to the letter E which in this case would be `2,0`. So, 123456 this time would equal: `AEDDAC`.

Summary:

```
test.php?password=123456 \\\ Client sends REQUEST with password

Code sends a GET request and receives input value for conversion.

Example:
Input Value: "9,5 (It has the value of A). 6,3 (It has the value of B). 0,1 (It has the value of C). 8,7 (It has the value of D). 4,2 (It has the value of E)"

Password is converted to letters, in which case 123456 would look like: CEBEAB
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: You don't have `9.8` or `2.0` in the string. You have `9,8` and `2,0`. How is the code supposed to know it's `9,8` and not `5,9` and `8,6`?

Comment: Are you trying to write your own hashing like algorithm?

Comment: I still have no idea how to do this code. But I think an explode and a siwtch would solve, just do not know where to start.

Comment: Ignore the points, they are actually commas

Comment: 9.8 and 2.0 is actually 9,8 and 2,0

Comment: Julio, you'd be surprised what you can accomplish on your own if you try. Please edit your question and fix the number formatting because it is confusing.

Comment: Edited. You can check it ?

Comment: @JúlioCésar is this question for a homework or for a live production system?

Comment: Homework, i need to solve it.

Comment: Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by making a map of the letters assigned to each number, then use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to convert each number to its associated value.

```
$input = '123456';

$map = [
    0 => 'C',
    1 => 'C',
    2 => 'E',
    3 => 'B',
    4 => 'E',
    5 => 'A',
    6 => 'B',
    7 => 'D',
    8 => 'D',
    9 => 'A'
];

$out = implode(  // converts the array returned by array_map to a string
    array_map(function($num) use ($map) {
        return $map[$num];  // maps each input number to its associated letter
    }, 
    str_split($input)) // split the input into an array of characters
);

echo $out; // Output: 'CEBEAB'
```